# Hide the underlying property name in Data Annotation validation error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have this asp.net core model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "id")]
    [StringLength(36, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

I added the `ModelBinder` attribute in order to rename the "ObjectId" field to "id".

When I trying to submit the model with bad values. For example:

```
{
    "id": "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
}
```

I'm getting back this response from the server:

```
{
     "id":["The field ObjectId must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 36."]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
     "id":["The field id must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 36."]
}
```

That's strange because the `key` ("id") was written in the right case. But in the `value` ("ObjectId") it was written in wrong.

My client shouldn't be aware of `ObjectId`. He just know `id`. How to fix messages like these?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *fix*? What is your desired output?

Comment: Edited the question. Added - "Expected output" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `DisplayName` attribute:

```
public class MyModel
{
  [ModelBinder(Name = "id")]
  [StringLength(36, MinimumLength = 3)]
  [DisplayName("id")]
  public string Id {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom error message on [StringLengthAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

```
public class MyModel
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "id")]
    [StringLength(36, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage="The field id must be a string with a minimum length of {1} and a maximum length of {2}.")]
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Excerpt from documentation page:

> You can use composite formatting placeholders in the **error message**: {0} is the name of the property; {1} is the maximum length; and {2} is the minimum length. The placeholders correspond to arguments that are passed to the String.Format method at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This solution is workaround since I have to manually set the error-message for each validator, for each model. Additionally, Also when I change the field name (for "id2" for example), I also have to edit all those messages agian. This not sound a smart step.

Answer (score 0):

For `StringLength`, it uses the default property name for constructing the error message which is expected.

If you prefer using the `Name` arugment from `ModelBinder`, you could implement your own `StringLength` arribute like

```
public class CustomStringLength : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public CustomStringLength(int maximumLength) 
        : base(maximumLength)
    {
    }
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {

        return base.FormatErrorMessage(name);
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var propertyName = validationContext.DisplayName;
        var propertyAttribute = validationContext.ObjectType
                                    .GetProperty(propertyName)
                                    .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ModelBinderAttribute));
        if (propertyAttribute is ModelBinderAttribute modelBinderAttribute)
        {
            validationContext.DisplayName = modelBinderAttribute.Name;
        }
        //validationContext.DisplayName = "Id";
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```
public class MyModel
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "id")]
    [CustomStringLength(36, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This solution have some significant down-sides. Assuming my application using many different types of validators - implement each one our self can be hard staff. So, it's no more then workaround. Wondering why Microsoft didn't implement it that way from the first time...

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever for this issue, I have submitted an issue with [Format Error Message with ModelBinder Name Arguments #10032](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10032), you could keep following this issue.

Comment: Great idea. Thanks!